# Adding multiple lines to one field

Tags: sql-server

I would like to create a view that has a part number, order number and any comments attached to the part number. Comments are stored in a table OEC. There is a record for each line of comments.

```
OEC.ord_no OEC.seq_no OEC.cmt_seq_no OEC.comment
123        1          1              Comment line 1
123        1          2              Comment line 2
```

The OEC will link to an OER table by OER.ord_no and OER.seq_no

I would like the view to return

```
OER.ord_no OER.item_no OEC_Comment
123        ABC         Comment line 1, Comment line 2
```

There is no limit to the number of lines a comment could possibly have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use table function that may help you

Comment: how can i use table function?

Comment: select OEC.ord_no,OER.item_no,stuff((select ','+OEC.OEC_Comment from OEC  where OEC.seq_no = OER.seq_no 
for xml path('')),1,1,'')
 as OEC_Comment
from OEC t
join OER o
on (o.ord_no = t.ord_no
and o.seq_no = t.seq_no)
group by OEC.ord_no,OER.item_no,OER.seq_no.   try this